# php compare two associative array value

Tags: php

**MySQL array**

[image]

**CSV file array**

[image]

I want to match this two different associative arrays "Url" value. Also I want remaining array value of CSV file i.e. DA, PA, MozRank, Linksln, and so on...

I hope some genius can help me

Thank you

Comment: Easy way is to compare `array_column($array1, 'url')` against `array_column($array2, 'url')`

Comment: What you need output

Comment: I want just matching URL value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check this custom PHP script returns you matched url from two array

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Function for match url and return data 
     */
    function matchArray($array1, $array2)
    {
        $index = 0;
        $return = array();
        $count1 = count($array1);
        $count2 = count($array2);
        for($i=0; $i < $count1; $i++)
        {
            for($j=0; $j < $count2; $j++)
            { 
                if($array1[$i]['url'] == $array2[$j]['url']) {
                    $return[$index]['url'] = $array2[$j]['url'];    // Add index which you want to get 
                    $return[$index]['DA'] = $array2[$j]['DA'];     // Add index which you want to get 
                    $return[$index]['PA'] = $array2[$j]['PA']; 
                    $return[$index]['MozRank'] = $array2[$j]['MozRank']; 
                }
                $index ++;
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($return); // this will return matched url form two array 
    }
$array1 = array(array('url' => 'AllConsuming.net' ),array('url' => 'app.brand-mention.com'),array('url' => 'www.microsoft.com'));
    $array2 = array(array('url' => 'AllConsuming.net', 'DA' => 48, 'PA'=> 54.4, 'MozRank'=> 5.4),array('url' => 'www.microsoft.com', 'DA' => 31.7, 'PA'=> 54.4, 'MozRank'=> 5.4));

matchArray($array1, $array2); // calling function 
 ?>
```

Comment: Hello, @Aman Kumar. Also, I have to need the remaining value of matched URL. i.e. DA, PA, MozRank and so on.. You can get the idea from above CSV file array. Thank you

Comment: Hello @Aman Kumar, Also, I have to update MySQL table. All fields of CSV file are available in MySQL table I need to just update match URL, remaining fields to MySQL existing table fields. Can you help me how can I do? Thank You...

Comment: Hello @Aman Kumar, Can you help me to find out unmatch URL from two array ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know which entries are indentical, proceed this way :

```
$array1 = array_column($ar1, 'url'); // return array('AllConsuming.net', 'http://app.brand-mention.com', 'https://www.microsoft.com', 'otherstuff')
$array2 = array_column($ar2, 'url'); // return array('AllConsuming.net', 'TravelIntelligence.net', 'otherstuff')

// compare these 2 arrays
$comp = array_intersect($aray1, $array2);
var_dump($comp); // output array('AllConsuming.net', 'otherstuff');
```